# How to add a profile and Sending and receiving messages to an android app

Tags: android

Hello everyone and have an awesome week. First of, I built an android app 3 months ago after following some android tutorial because I have no experience in programming. However, my question is this is it possible for me to make any update on the app? For example, for now a user can add and un-add friends, can also send and view a video or an image. How can I make a user profile in order to make the user able to update his info and change his profile pic. I also want to know how to start a conversation with another user because for now when I click on a friend on my friends list nothing happening, I want to start a conversation if I did so. To clarify, I want to the user to be able to start a conversation with any member on his friends list. Second, I want the user to have a profile within the ability to add some personal images if he/she wants. See the pic below. 
[enter link description here](http://postimg.org/image/atnr1dnaz/)

[enter link description here](http://postimg.org/image/nexwwvp6f/)

Comment: The site is meant for programming problems, not for expecting others to do your work. Please tell us what you have tried and what you are stuck with.

Comment: Thanks my friend, but if you asking what I have tried I'll tell you nothing because I don't know where to start;however, the app that I have built is a similar to "SnapChat" but what I needed to know is how to make a user profile.

Comment: I only need they idea if you can help me with it. By the way if you were asking yourself, if I love programming why didn't I go to college and learn it. The answer is that I'm not in college and in my country they don't teach us programming unless if you choice to do so in college

Comment: which I'm not a college student; therefore I have to wait until that time come. But I would rather to have a bit knowledge at least before that day come.

Comment: You don't need to go to college to learn programming. I learned it myself :) To add messaging: 1) buy a server, 2) learn php and SQL, 3) set up a MySQL table on your server, 4) write a php script that handles the database connection, 5) encode the result, 6) do a web request in your app, 7) decode the result, 8) put the messages into the local SQLite database, 9) display the messages. **You see, it's a lot of work - You should really start with an easier app.** (Of course I will not give you an example for that code because it would take me 2-3 weeks to write it)